# Build hierarchy from joined records with mysql

Tags: mysql, json, hierarchy

```
Table1 (users): id, name
Table2 (roles): id, name
Table3 (user-roles): userid, roleid
```

The desired results in the following JSON:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "name":"username",
  "roles":[
     {
       "id":1
       "name":"admin"
     },
     {
       "id":2,
       "name":"community manager"
     }
  ]
}
```

Is there a MySQL syntax which outputs the desired result for UNLIMITED joins?

On hold: Not sure, how could i phrase this better.
There are two tables which are in relation through a third one (user-roles).
Records should be arranged to a hierarchy as JSON, based on the query JOIN statements.

See MSSQL soulution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server

Comment: Mysql won't do it( You have to use nodejs or php or golang or something else...

Comment: MySQL doesn't output JSON. What do you use to do the query?

Comment: what version of MySQL server you use?

Answer (score 1):

This query return what you want but it will be work just on MySQL 8.0 or higher

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('id', users.id, 'name', users.name, 'roles', JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', roles.id, 'name', roles.name)))
FROM users
  INNER JOIN user_roles
  ON users.id = user_roles.userid

  INNER JOIN roles
  ON user_roles.roleid = roles.id
GROUP BY users.id;
```

Comment: Isn't GROUP BY users.id prevent to retrive multiple roles for each user?

Comment: vice versa `GROUP BY` makes possible use multiple values in one row grouped by some value `users.id` in this case

Comment: i mean when using GROUP BY there will be only one record for each 'user'
and that record only will contain one joined record from 'roles', the rest of the joined role records are not accessibe. Aren't they?
Or the JSON_OBJECT  and JSON_ARRAYGG functions changing this behaviour?

Comment: no `JSON_ARRAYGG` is aggregation function it will join all `JSON_OBJECT`s for user